# Android App Rejection SPLIT_BUNDLE 15: Policy Declaration

Tags: android, android-studio

SPLIT_BUNDLE 15: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your app accessing sensitive data(Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address) of user that's why your app rejected. So you have to avoid use id's or have to give valid description why you need use id's.

Comment: Issue found: Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy
Your app must be in compliance with this policy.